Will Allah SWT return someone that i lost because of my fault?
Because I am not a perfect human being, I lost someone I love very much due to my mistakes and stupidity. I keep asking for forgiveness from him and from Allah SWT, as He is the creator of the love of my life.
I wonder if Allah will change his heart and then bring him back to me when He has fully forgiven me. Or, if He won't, will Allah give me someone better? I do believe that when Allah takes something away from me, He will give me something much better than I can ever imagine. Or will I always be punished by Allah SWT to be alone because I hurt His creation whom I love deeply?

The question is not answerable as we are not clairvoyant. You do dua and then expect that whatever will happen will be for the better.
